# Почему file_put_contents() создает пустой файл?

Tags: php

В цикле через file_get_contents() открываются файлы, и через file_put_contents() сохраняются:

```
$urlHeaders = @get_headers($filesURL[$i]);
if(strpos($urlHeaders[0], '200')) {
    $file = file_get_contents($filesURL[$i]);
    file_put_contents($landingsDir."/".$landingName."/".$filesPath[$i]."/".pathinfo($filesURL[$i])["basename"], $file);
}
```

Все файлы сохраняются пустыми, будь то картинки или текстовые файлы.

Comment: что выводит `strlen($file);`? Выведите значение `$landingsDir."/".$landingName."/".$filesPath[$i]."/".pathinfo($filesURL[$i])["basename"]`, затем что выводит `ls -la этот-файл`

Comment: Файлов много strlen($file) выводит 73300
183694
137352
15038
30762
26469
40337
10792
10792
24711
18221
21056
23533
25227
12265
24525
21383
24525
23320
12344
23320
14858
19538
14858
24711
21232
24711
18221
15162
18221
21056
20474
21056
23533
14145
23533
25227
21794
25227
12265
16065
12265
1278
1139
4828
103466
103466
54436
103264
76329
1965
5397
672
1664
1993
6712
619
1467
5617
5397
701
770895
240
242
296
250
267
1965
5397
5617
5397
33453
687
75599
40402
5904
11068
4330
21652
9025

Comment: насчет ls -la не понял, как вывести

Comment: А место на диске есть ?

Comment: Да, это на локальном сервере

Comment: файлы тащите тоже с локального ресурса? поставьте ini_set('display_errors', 1); в начале скрипта, если чё покажет - добавьте к вопросу

Answer (score 0):

Нужно проверить не пустая ли переменная $file во время сохранения (перед вызовом file_put_contents), может пустые значения или если вы пытаетесь не текстовые файлы читать и сохранять (какие то бинарные символы, которые не видны при просмотре).